# (My)SQL: Get new ids in an 'INSERT INTO ... SELECT'

Tags: sql, auto-increment, bulkinsert

I have to insert into one table the records selected from another table and (then) update the former table with the generated id for the latter. How can I do it?

E.g.

input_table:

```
input_table:  code  new_id
               aa    NULL
               bb    NULL


output_table:  id(auto_increment)  code
                ...                ...
```

SQL:

```
INSERT INTO output_table (code) SELECT code FROM input_table;

UPDATE input_table "WITH THE NEW IDS"
```

Result:

```
input_table:   code  new_id
                aa    100
                bb    101

output_table:   id   code
                ...  ...
                100  aa
                101  bb
```

For several reasons I cannot rely on the uniqueness of `code` in `output_table`.

Any hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set @max_orig_id = coalesce((select max(id) from output_table),0);
insert into output_table (code) select code from input_table;
update input_table join output_table on input_table.code=output_table.code and output_table.id > @max_orig_id set input_table.new_id=output_table.id;
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the answers above are multi-user safe. If you have to have concurrent access, I suggest abandoning the auto-increment and using your own sequence for IDs. Unfortunately, MySQL lacks `CREATE SEQUENCE`, but you can simulate one with functions backed by a hidden last-value table. (Don't forget to lock the table completely during the function so that multiple users get distinct IDs.) Then get a new ID number from the function any supply it to both the `INSERT` and `UPDATE` statements.

Some dialects support `INSERT ... RETURNING <column value>` but MySQL can't.

Comment: try not to use phrases like "answers above", since answers don't appear in a fixed order